# Personalizing 'to' field with EmailMultiAlternatives

Tags: django, mailer

I'm using EmailMultiAlternatives to serve a lot of our emails to customers. We'd ideally like to change the 'to' field so that it reflects their name rather than the email address itself, as apparently that makes spam filters less likely to block your email.

I know how to change the from field from this:

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives("subject", text_content, "from@bla", ["to@bla"])
```

to this:

```
 msg = EmailMultiAlternatives("subject", text_content, "from, bla <from@bla>", ["to@bla"])
```

but this doesn't seem to work for the 'to' field.

Any suggestions for how I could fix the 'to' field too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will work for a `to` field:

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives("subject", text_content, 
                             "from@example.com", 
                             ["Some Name <to@example.com>"])
```

What will fail is the presence of a comma (`,`) anywhere in the recipient string, because Django will split the recipient into two at that point. This is pretty hard baked into the underlying `EmailMessage` class and you would have to override it non-trivially if you wanted to change that behaviour.

That said, I am not sure it is worth the effort. I don't know many email clients that show you the name that was in the `To:` field (given that, well, it's you), and in the absence of evidence to the contrary I would say that it can't be a key factor in spam scoring because most bulk senders out there just use a plain email address in the `To:` field.